# Change affinity (not priority) process with WMI

Tags: process, wmi, affinity

In C# app and WMI I try to change the proccess's affinity (like the taskmanager).

I must do it for a remote computer. `System.Diagnostics` don't do that.

I don't find WMI classes.
There are somes classes like `Win32_NamedJobObjectProcess`, `Win32_NamedJobObjectLimit` or `Win32_NamedJobObjectLimitSetting` but it seems to be for affinites's jobs kernel...

Is it possible ? Which classes ?
in C#, ps1, vbs...

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you talking about process your code working on or any process in Windows?

Comment: Any process on the remote computer

Comment: 6 years later, I want to do the same thing. Any luck?

Comment: No... no escape...